# MediaPlayer shows wrong durations for some MP3 files

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I'm developing an app that plays every verse of the Quran. There are 6348 audio files, and they're all hosted by someone else and their URL is of a specific format (e.g. [www.url.com/{001-001}](http://www.url.com/%7B001-001%7D)).

Now for a lot of the verses, when I try to get the mp3 file's duration, it returns the wrong duration. An example being this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lssoh5abug9xezz/002-003-AR.mp3?dl=0. It keeps giving me the duration as 6189 when the file is around 9 seconds long.

This issue applies to some files while others seem fine. How can I fix this issue? Downloading all 6348 files and making changes to them isn't an option due to the sheer number.

I have tried using both `mediaPlayer.getDuration()` as well as the following method, but with the same results:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriever.setDataSource("https://www.alislam.org/quran/search2/mp3-3/002-003-AR.mp3", new HashMap<String, String>());
try {
    URL url1=new URL("https://www.alislam.org/quran/search2/mp3-3/002-003-AR.mp3");
    AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(url1.);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i=0; i < 40; i++){
    String m = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(i);
    System.out.println("********************** " + m);
}
```

1. I'm assuming it's an issue with the MP3 files themselves. Is that
   the case?
2. What would be the best way to get around this without having to modify each file and re-upload them? Clearly if I'm able to play it in the browser and it shows the correct 9 seconds, I should be able to get that 9 second value using some way if not the above mentioned ways?
3. I need this duration primarily to set `seekBar.setMax(duration);` Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are getting the total duration as milliseconds. You need to convert it to seconds and minutes as follows:

```
 int seconds = totalDuration / 1000;
 int mm = seconds % 3600 / 60;
 int ss = seconds % 60;
```

Then format these values using a string:

```
String str = String.format ( "%02d:%02d"  , mm , ss );
```

Notice the totalDuration value is important here. The final String is also needed as is.

Comment: Thanks, but clearly you didn't even read my question and just pasted the answer from another question i believe. It has nothing to do with any conversion and it only affects certain files.

Comment: Yeah. I copy-pasted my answer from another question that I never heard about; unless that question is my project's codes. Anyway, I'd like to thank me for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

When I open the file "h**ps://www.alislam.org/quran/search2/mp3-3/002-003-AR.mp3" in an mp3 editor, it has a duration of 6 seconds

Comment: That's the thing. Does that mean it's something fundamentally wrong with the file itself? Because when I open the URL in Chrome, it clearly plays for 0:09 and displays 9 seconds as the total duration as well. So there seems to be some kind of metadata, which Chrome can see but MediaPlayer can't?

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with the file. Playing ends after 6th second, then jumped to 12th second.